# Woods-Saxon energy levels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, eigenvalue

I'm trying to calculate the bound state energy levels for a Woods-Saxon potential, given by:

$$V(r) = -\frac{V_{0}}{1+\exp(\frac{r-R}{a})}$$

I'm using Numerov's matrix method, which led me to:

$$H\psi = E\psi, \hspace{2cm} H= -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}B^{-1}A + V$$

with:

$$ A = \frac{1}{d^{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
 -2 & 1  & 0  & 0 & 0 & ...\\ 
 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0  & ...\\ 
 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & ... \\ 
 0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & ... \\ 
 ... & ...  & ...  & ...  & ...  & ... \\ 
\end{pmatrix} $$

$$ B = \frac{1}{12}\begin{pmatrix}
 10 & 1  & 0  & 0 & 0 & ...\\ 
 1 & 10 & 1 & 0 & 0  & ...\\ 
 0 & 1 & 10 & 1 & 0 & ... \\ 
 0 & 0 & 1 & 10 & 1 & ... \\ 
 ... & ...  & ...  & ...  & ...  & ... \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$  V = \begin{pmatrix}
 V_{1} & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & ...\\ 
 0 & V_{2} & 0 & 0 & 0  & ...\\ 
 0 & 0 & V_{3} & 0 & 0 & ... \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & V_{4} & 0 & ... \\ 
 ... & ...  & ...  & ...  & ...  & ... \\ 
\end{pmatrix} $$

$$ \psi = \begin{pmatrix}
\psi_{1}\\ 
\psi_{2}\\ 
\psi_{3}\\ 
\psi_{4}\\ 
...\\ 
\end{pmatrix} $$

as made in [Bhat *et al* (2015)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/295148034_Numerical_solution_of_Schroedinger_equation_using_matrix_Numerov_method_with_Woods_-_Saxon_potential).

However, this is an eigenvalue equation, and I get $n$ eigenvalues, one for each point in space $(r_{n} = n\cdot dr)$, and I don't know what to do with them. How can I know which ones are the allowed energy states? I think I should set some boundary conditions for the wave function, but I'm not sure how to do it. Here's most of my Python code, the rest is just plots and stuff.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.linalg
from scipy.sparse import diags

def WS(r, V0, R, a):
    return -V0/(1.0+sp.exp((r-R)/a))
hc = 197  
m = 939.57   # MeV/c2
V0 = 50   # MeV
a = 0.6   # fm
R = 5.0   # fm

dr = 0.1
r0 = 0.0
n = 100
r = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    r[i] = r0 + i*dr

A = diags([np.full(n,-2), np.full(n-1,1), np.full(n-1,1)], [0, -1, 1]).toarray()/(dr**2)
B = (1.0/12.0)*diags([np.full(n,10), np.full(n-1,1), np.full(n-1,1)], [0, -1, 1]).toarray()
V = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    V[i,i] = WS(r[i], V0, R, a)
H = (-hc**2/(2*m))*np.dot(np.linalg.inv(B), A) + V

E = np.linalg.eig(H)[0]
psi = scipy.linalg.solve(H, E)
```

So the big question is: how can I get the bound-state allowed energies? What am I missing, or what did I wrong?

Comment: I'm not reading all that code but are you treating the energy level as a variable?  This looks like a numerical method for solving an ODE or PDE and you either need the constant E or you need it to fall out.  The standard procedure is to make E a variable and add dE/dx = 0, dE/dt = 0, etc.  This works well with the relaxation method where you can start with a guess involving exact solutions to another problem.  If this is not the issue someone else may be able to help.

Comment: Yeah, the eigenvalues of the discrete matrix are not necessarily related to the eigenvalues of the differential operator.  That is your first mistake.

Comment: Vincente, did you end up solving your problem? I would be very interested in learning about the resolution. Thank you!